# Does hibernation on host machine damage guest machine?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, hibernate

I have a host machine running Windows 10 and a guest machine running Linux. Sometimes I hibernate the host but I forget to shutdown the guest machine.

Does hibernation on the host machine while the guest machine is running, can damage the guest machine?

What if the guest's hard drive is a physical external hard drive?

Comment: At least for me (with 5.0.10) the guest clocks 'stand still' and thus become wrong by amount of hibernation. Whether this counts as damage depends on you; I find it annoying enough to avoid doing it. I haven't tried an external disk but I see no reason it should make a difference as long as you don't disconnect it during the 'warp' -- and an internal drive _can_ be removed also.

Answer (score 2):

It is known issue in VirualBox running on Windows:

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/14374

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, when a computer goes into hibernation, it takes everything in RAM and writes it to the hard drive and then powers down.  When it boots up, it reverses the process and reads everything that was written to the hibernation file into RAM.  If the external drive is in the same port and unlocked when the computer powers up from hibernation, then it should resume as if nothing happened.  VirtualBox shouldn't actually care which port the hard drive is plugged into if you are using a virtual hard drive on the external drive, it only cares about the path to the drive.  If you're forwarding the USB directly to the VM, it mostly shouldn't matter as I believe that VirtualBox goes by USB IDs when forwarding USB to VMs.

Comment: on a windows system, the order of the plugged in devices matters

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't matter, or at least I can't imagine any reason it would. Caveat: I speak purely from theory. I use VMs but I never hibernate and never have. So maybe someone will show I'm wrong, it's happened before, but I'd be real surprised.